# simple hang man game which gives me issues , uses stings and replace

Tags: python

hello i am curretly struggling , i am new to code and just want to see what i can fix with my code. its a simple hang man game. i just keep getting a 0 responce. im planning to add multiplal levels such as a easy , med and hard dif. I have tried to fix the code but because i am new i cannot. Someone please shed some light.

```
import random

answerlist = ["bap" , "wow" , "ok" , "no" ]

random.shuffle(answerlist)

answer = list(answerlist[0])

#print(answer)

#empty list called display
display = []

#adds the variable answer to display
display.extend(answer)

#print(used)

#interates through the list 'display'

for i in range (len(display)):
            #replaces each index in the list with '__'
            display[i] ="_"
# the join command puts a space between each "__"
print (' ' .join(display))
print ()

#counter stops the game once all letters guessed
count  = 0

#keeps asking user untill all letters guessed

while count < len(answer):
                guess = input("please take a guess: ")
                guess = guess.lower()
                print (count)

# iterates through the letters in answer

for i in range(len(answer)):

#if  the guessed letter matches the letter
# in the answer

                if answer [i] == guess :
# replace the index of that guess with
# the actual letter they guessed
                             display[i] = guess
                count = count + 1

                #print (used)

#print out the new string with guessed letters in
                print (' '.join(display))
                print()

print("well done , you have won")
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite messy so it's hard to say what the issue really is. Several suggestions:
1. Why do you do `display.extend(answer)` and set display to `_` later in the code? I fail to see what it does.
2. `count = count + 1` should be activated only if the user gets a letter right? In your syntax count increases every time you check a letter

Also, please paste your code in the right syntax so it's easier to debug for you.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the formatting I'm pretty sure your problem comes from this portion:

```
while count < len(answer):
    guess = input("please take a guess: ")
    guess = guess.lower()
    print (count)
```

count is set to 0 and never changes therefore the while loop will continue on forever.